# How can we test class have no default constructor? Class is not instantiable?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

How can I write a unit test for constructor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In that case I think you don't need the constructor since you are using a static const.
But, if you want to have a constructor then try using a factory constructor like this: `factory CacheKeys() => CacheKeys._();`